# Using Local Storage As a RecordSet

Tags: ios, web-applications, mobile-safari, recordset, dashcode

I'm doing a offline web application using Dashcode which uses a lot of data from a local storage via the [Dashcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashcode)'s RecordSet function, but I was testing this all using a local XML file as example, but now I need something that I can read and write(and still be usable as a RecordSet), so how can I make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) is [included with iOS.](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html)

Comment: OP tagged the question with web-applications and mobile-safari. How does SQLite helps?

Comment: @Black: So... *Local storage*, right?  Dashcode's RecordSet function is apparently read-only.